# Install new package in H2O Flow UI

Tags: h2o

I want to use other library like tensorflow in H2O flow UI.

how can i install and import new library?

I found this project
https://github.com/gdtm86/sparklingwater-examples/tree/master/h2o-examples-flow_ui

and I tried this code.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.dataFrame
```

and this is error.

```
[stdin]:2:13: error: unexpected .
  import org.apache.spark.sql.dataFrame
            ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't install packages into Flow, Flow is simply the web UI that comes with H2O-3 (H2O-3 has multiple APIs). For more details on what Flow is please see the [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/flow.html). Note: Sparkling Water is H2O-3's integration with Spark.